# unable to collect subprocess output on windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to collect subprocess output on Windows, and unable to do so. Can you point out what i am doing wrong?

Overall, grepword-p.py reads a 'search word' and an 'argument list of files/dirs' and spawns 'count' number of child workers to do the work. I was looking to collect output from each worker back and sort the output which is when I tried "Popening" with stdout, and stderr arguments. But I get errors as I show below -

**grepword-p.py**

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import argparse

def parse_options():
    ....
    return args, args.word, args.files

def get_files(args, recurse):
    ...
    return files

child = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "grepword-p-child.py")
opts, word, args = parse_options()
filelist = get_files(args, opts.recurse)
files_per_process = len(filelist) // opts.count
start, end = 0, files_per_process + (len(filelist) % opts.count)
number = 1

pipes=[]
while start < len(filelist):
    command = [sys.executable, child]
    if opts.debug:
        command.append(str(number))
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
            command,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            # stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
    pipe.stdin.write(word.encode("utf-8") + b"\n")
    for filename in filelist[start:end]:
        pipe.stdin.write(filename.encode("utf-8") + b"\n")
    pipe.stdin.close
    print("sent data to worker {}".format(number))
    number += 1
    start, end = end, end + files_per_process

try:
    stdouts, stderrs = ([], [])
    while pipes:
        pipe = pipes.pop()
        # pipe.wait
        out, err = pipe.communicate()
        stdouts.append(out.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
        stderrs.append(err.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
    print("Output from all workers\n{}\n".format(sorted(stdouts)))
    print("Error from all workers\n{}\n".format(sorted(stderrs)))

except Exception as err:
    exc_typ, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    print("Exception at line {}".format(exc_tb.lineno))

print("done")
```

**grepword-p-child.py**

```
import sys

BLOCK_SIZE = 1000

try:
    number = "{0}: ".format(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ""
    stdin = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
    lines = stdin.decode("utf-8", "ignore").splitlines()
    word = lines[0].rstrip()

    for filename in lines[1:]:
        filename = filename.rstrip()
        previous = ""
        try:
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                while True:
                    current = f.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
                    if not current:
                        break
                    current = current.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
                    if (word in current or
                        word in previous[-len(word):] + current[:len(word)]):
                        print("{0}{1}".format(number, filename))
                        break
                    if len(current) != BLOCK_SIZE:
                        break
                    previous = current
        except Exception as err:
            print("error here")
            print("{0}{1}".format(number, err))

except Exception as err:
    exc_typ, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    print("Exception at line {}".format(exc_tb.lineno))
```

**Output**

```
c:\Python27\user_modules>python grepword-p.py --count 2 --debug True --recurse False child c:\Python27\user_modules
sent data to worker 1
sent data to worker 2
Output from all workers
[]

Error from all workers
[]

done

c:\Python27\user_modules>Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Sorry for the clutter with the likely unnecessary try/excepts - just trying to debug this and having a heartache :P

Comment: `pipe.stdin.close` is not closing `stdin`: `pipe.stdin.close()` does

Comment: there's way too much code for a real [mcve] BTW. Noone said that you had to post your _real_ code.

Comment: switching to `close()` didnt make a difference :(

Comment: ok switched to using `multiprocessing` module [here](https://gist.github.com/leonpanokarren/0c310c0760c186a4c5df2e3af0a7a422) for now; but would like to know what is wrong with the `subprocess` module example above

Comment: there's just too much code for someone to figure out. Check below: do you see any answer? no? then ask yourself why.